# Extract a portion of text from a file name

Tags: bash, shell, substring, glob

I have files with following names, Each file name contains the information of Area code and house number. I'm new to scripting. How to write bash script for extracting area code and house number?

```
ID-Final_RDX_301_002-14_33_1992

Area code is 301
house number is 002

ID-Final_RDX-311-004-14_28_1992

Area code is 311
house number is 004

ID-Final_RDX311021-14_28_1992

Area code is 311
house number is 021

ID-Final_RDX-XT-Se3-14_28_1992

Area code is XT
house number is Se3

ID-Final_RDX-XT-Se11-14_28_1992

Area code is XT
house number is Se11
```

Comment: do you need those strings `Area code is <number> ... house number is <number>` to be outputted literally?

Comment: Want to extract the area code and house number. Also need to print the same to a text file

Comment: From the file name by using script need have to extract the area code and house number

Comment: post the final expected result

Comment: why this sequence `311021` should be considered as `311` and `021`?

Comment: delimiter are not consistent `-` and `_` and sometimes missing is it a typo or can you give a rule to split file name ?

Comment: Just a touch up on [**sjsam's answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48173235/2772061) `find . -type f -name "ID-Final*" -exec awk -vfile={} 'BEGIN{
split(file,res,"-|_");
printf "{} \nArea Code is %s \nHouse Number is %s%s",res[4],res[5],ORS
}' \; > output.txt
` This will print exactly what you need.

Comment: @SriniV Huh? hard coding newlines(`\n`) in `awk` scripts make them less portable..You should use the built-in variable `ORS` instead :-). But that is not a big deal here.. The deal though is the inconsistent file naming scheme ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your filenames doesn't follow a pattern as mentioned in [[this]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48169557/extract-a-portion-of-text-from-a-file-name#comment83320685_48169557) comment. But I hope it is a typo. If that is the case, you could do something in similar terms as mentioned below :

```
find . -type f -name "ID-Final*" -exec awk -vfile={} 'BEGIN{
split(file,res,"-|_");
printf "Area Code : %s House Number : %s%s",res[4],res[5],ORS
}' \;
Area Code : 311 House Number : 004
Area Code : 14 House Number : 28
Area Code : XT House Number : Se3
Area Code : XT House Number : Se11
Area Code : 301 House Number : 002
```

---

Well,if the missing `-/_`s are intentional, then you need much more than this simple `awk` to solve this.